# Can we use 'calm' as a noun?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, nouns

I was conversing with a friend and she told me that, "Only the hardcore survive". I replied with "I believe only the calm survive."

I'm not a native speaker so I don't know if we can use calm in this situation. If we don't, can someone suggest some alternatives instead of calm?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96787/discussion-on-question-by-nina-can-we-use-calm-as-a-noun).

Answer (score 4):

What both you and your friend have done is made an adjective (*hardcore*, *calm*) into a noun through the process of [nominalization](https://www.thoughtco.com/nominalization-in-grammar-1691430). In this case, both of you use the adjective form to specify a group of people who have that quality: the *hardcore* (people), the *calm* (people). We see this in many established idioms and proverbs:

> Blessed are the meek, for they shall inherit the Earth ([Matthew 5:5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_5:5))
>
> How are the mighty fallen! ([2 Samuel 1:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel%201%3A19-27&version=KJV))

Both *the meek* and *the mighty* describe a group of people who have that quality. These usages are often not recorded in dictionaries; *calm* is does not appear as a noun referring to people in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel%201%3A19-27&version=KJV). However, if it describes a person, using an adjective with a definite article as a noun is one way to generalize about a group of people:

> I believe only the calm survive.
>
> The bold may win the day yet.
>
> There are the quick and the dead.

One other thing to notice - all of these examples use plural [concord](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-concord-grammar-1689784), that is, the verb agrees with a plural noun. Saying "I believe only the calm *survive*" denotes an implied plural subject corresponding to the verb. (Example: "the calm *people* survive".) If you had said "I believe only the calm survives," then the verb would suggest a singular subject, and might refer to various singular meanings for *calm*.

Comment: The plural concord matters here. If folks were talking about a roiled sea versus a calm one, they could say the calm is better with singular concord. But here you get plural concord for the multitudes of the meek. :)

Comment: Great point - *the calm survives* versus *the calm survive* is completely different. I'll update.

Comment: How the mighty **are** fallen! [more usual] And subject-verb agreement. Let concord reign.

Answer (score 1):

The word "calm" can absolutely be a noun. The OED has several definitions that are nouns. These two are the most relevant to your example:

> c. **figurative of social or political conditions and circumstances.**
>
> 1547   J. Harrison Exhort. Scottes 210   The stormes of this
>   tempestious worlde, shall shortely come to a calme.
>
> 1609   Shakespeare Troilus & Cressida i. iii. 100   The vnitie and
>   married calme of states.
>
> 1781   W. Cowper Friendship xxiii   Religion should..make a calm of
>   human life.
>
> 1850   J. C. Calhoun Wks. (1874) IV. 24   Till our free and popular
>   institutions are succeeded by the calm of despotism.
>
> d. **figurative of the mind, feelings, or demeanour; = calmness n.**
>
> 1609   Shakespeare Troilus & Cressida iv. i. 16   Our blouds are now
>   in calme .
>
> 1719   D. Defoe Life Robinson Crusoe 234   All my Calm of Mind..seem'd
>   to be suspended.
>
> 1807   Wordsworth Poems II. 108   A good Man's calm, A great Man's
>   happiness.
>
> 1879   F. W. Farrar Life & Work St. Paul II. ix. xliii. 376   In that
>   desperate crisis one man retained his calm and courage.